# Select equivalent rows [A-B & B-A]

Tags: r

My problem seems to be very simple but I'm not able to solve it since hours…

I have a matrix such this one:

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    1
[3,]    2    1
[4,]    3    4
```

I want to select the rows which have the same information, without regard to the order of the column.
For instance row1 (1;2) and  row2  (2;1). Then, i want to delete them, except one.

I have written this function, but it doesn't work…

```
f<-function(x){
     i<-1
     repeat
     {
     a<-c()
     a<-c(which(x[i,1]==x[,2] & x[i,2]==x[,1]))
          if(!is.null(a)) {x<-x[-c(a),]}
          if(i>=nrow(x)) {break} else {i<-i+1}
     }
     x
} 
f(data)
```

Somebody could give me a hint for this ?

Comment: Does the order of the elements within a row matter? For example, does it have to be `1,2` or can it also be `2,1`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Like this:

```
unique(t(apply(mat, 1, sort)))
```

Note that output rows are sorted, so for example an "unmatched" row like `c(5, 1)` in the original data will appear as `c(1, 5)` in the output. If instead you want the output rows to be as they are in the input, then you can do:

```
mat[!duplicated(t(apply(mat, 1, sort))), ]
```