# How to remove duplicate pair-wise columns

Tags: r

Consider the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
           V2 = c("B", "C", "A", "C", "A", "B"),
           n = c(1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2))
```

How can I remove duplicate pair-wise columns so that the output looks like:

```
#   V1 V2 n
#1  A  B 1
#2  A  C 3
#3  B  C 2
```

I tried `unique()` and `duplicated()` to no avail.

Comment: This looks to be similar: [Select equivalent rows - a-b b-a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647875/select-equivalent-rows-a-b-b-a/19648451#19648451)

Comment: @thelatemail It is quite similar, perhaps even a duplicate.  That other question is more well-written - it is more clear what is desired.  This question should be edited to show the true intent (or closed as a duplicate or unclear).

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this is the simplest way of doing it (transposing can be computationally expensive) but this would work with your data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
                 V2 = c("B", "C", "A", "C", "A", "B"),
                 n = c(1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2))
```

First, sort the data frame row-wise, so your value-pairs become true duplicates.

```
df <- data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, sort)))
```

Then you can just apply the `unique` function.

```
df <- unique(df)
```

If your column names and order are important, you'll have to re-establish those.

```
names(df) <- c("n", "V1", "V2")
df <- df[, c("V1", "V2", "n")]
```

Comment: Very elegant solution. Incredibly helpful. Been stuck on this exact same issue for hours until I ran across your post. Thank you for posting.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to reshape (`xtabs(n~..)`) the dataset ('df') to wide format, set the lower triangular matrix to 0, and remove the rows with "Freq" equal to 0.

```
m1 <- xtabs(n~V1+V2, df)
m1[lower.tri(m1)] <- 0
subset(as.data.frame(m1), Freq!=0)
#  V1 V2 Freq
#4  A  B    1
#7  A  C    3
#8  B  C    2
```