# Unique case of finding duplicate values flexibly across columns in R

Tags: r, duplicates, row

I have a dataset similar to the following:

```
df <- data.frame(animal_1 = c("cat", "dog", "mouse", "squirrel"),
                 predation_type = c("eats", "eats", "eaten by", "eats"),
                 animal_2 = c("mouse", "squirrel", "cat", "nuts"))

> df
  animal_1 predation_type animal_2
1      cat           eats    mouse
2      dog           eats squirrel
3    mouse       eaten by      cat
4 squirrel           eats     nuts
```

I am looking for code that identifies row 1 and row 3 as duplicates since they are showing the same phenomenon (a cat eating a mouse or a mouse being eaten by a cat). I'm not sure how to even ask what kind of duplicate case I'm looking for so I'm hoping someone can help. I've tried combining the text into one column (i.e., "catmouse", "dogsquirrel", etc.) and then inverting the letters but that quickly proved too complex.

Thanks so much for any help you can provide.

Comment: `t(apply(df[ , c(1, 3)], 1, sort))` as described e.g. here: [Select equivalent rows A-B & B-A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647875/select-equivalent-rows-a-b-b-a); [Removing duplicate combinations irrespective of order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028369/removing-duplicate-combinations-irrespective-of-order). Also `pmin(df$animal_1, df$animal_2)`; `pmax(df$animal_1, df$animal_2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tidyverse**

```r
df <- data.frame(animal_1 = c("cat", "dog", "mouse", "squirrel"),
                 predation_type = c("eats", "eats", "eaten by", "eats"),
                 animal_2 = c("mouse", "squirrel", "cat", "nuts"))
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(duplicates = str_c(sort(c_across(c(1, 3))), collapse = "")) %>% 
  group_by(duplicates) %>% 
  mutate(duplicates = n() > 1) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   animal_1 predation_type animal_2 duplicates
#>   <chr>    <chr>          <chr>    <lgl>     
#> 1 cat      eats           mouse    TRUE      
#> 2 dog      eats           squirrel FALSE     
#> 3 mouse    eaten by       cat      TRUE      
#> 4 squirrel eats           nuts     FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

removing duplicates

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  filter(!duplicated(map2(animal_1, animal_2, ~str_c(sort((c(.x, .y))), collapse = ""))))
#>   animal_1 predation_type animal_2
#> 1      cat           eats    mouse
#> 2      dog           eats squirrel
#> 3 squirrel           eats     nuts
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi Yuriy, thanks so much, your first solution worked perfectly. And I appreciate learning how to do this in Tidyverse. Now that I have identified the duplicates, what would be the best way to eliminate one of each duplicate from the dataframe?

Comment: Ah, wait I think I figured it out with: 

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(duplicates = str_c(sort(c_across(c(1, 3))), collapse = "")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(duplicates) %>% 
  filter(row_number() == 1) %>% 
  mutate(duplicates = n() > 1) %>% 
  ungroup()

Comment: Great! If you believe this answer was helpful for you, you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this answer :)

Comment: Ah, great! Done. Very new to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can `sort()` the dataframe to make `duplicated()` useful.

```
newdf = df[, c('animal_1', 'animal_2')]

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  newdf[i, ] = sort(df[i,])
}

newdf[!(duplicated(newdf$animal_1) & duplicated(newdf$animal_2)),]

  animal_1 animal_2
1      cat    mouse
2      dog squirrel
4     nuts squirrel
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried this but was getting warning messages and the output had three null values.